# Return random item from tuple - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use the command $random and be sent a random item from the tuple. This code should work, however, I'm getting an error. I've tried putting the tuple and random.choice before bot.command which works and doesn't produce an error, but it only generates a random item if I run the program again. It will pick one item and simply return that instead of returning a random one each time.

```
@bot.command(name='random', help='Returns a random, interesting fact.')
async def random(ctx):
    random_messages = ("McDonald’s once made bubblegum-flavored broccoli.",
                       "Some fungi create zombies, then control their minds.",
                       "The first oranges weren’t orange. They were green.")
    random.choice(random_messages)
    await ctx.send(random_messages)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

**EDIT:** I needed to use a different name for the function that wasn't the same as the random module. Also, I updated random_messages by assigning it to the random.choice() command.

Working code:

```
@bot.command(name='random', help='Returns a random, interesting fact.')
async def randomfact(ctx):
    random_messages = ("McDonald’s once made bubblegum-flavored broccoli.",
                       "Some fungi create zombies, then control their minds.",
                       "The first oranges weren’t orange. They were green.")
    random_messages = random.choice(random_messages)
    await ctx.send(random_messages)
```

Comment: The function name and the module name are identical. Change the function name to `get_random_item` or import the module in a different name. i.e `import random as rd` (i think the first option is better)

Comment: You use the name `random` twice and forgot to actually use the result of `random.choice()`.

Comment: That makes much more sense.  It works now, thanks!